# SharePoint 2013 - How do we reference a javascript file into a script editor?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a .js script file that I would like to embed within various publishing pages.  Is there a web part or something I can use to reference my js file, rather than copying and pasting it into every script editor block, for each publishing page?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a custom page layout and putting the js file link directly into the page layout. Then when publishing pages are created using your page layout, there isn't any extra step you need to do. I've done this in 2010 in several places and it works well.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/03/03/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/